change names for photos
While I have shotwell, I feel the only way to organise my photos is to rename them in the folders and then import then instead of the other way around. If I import photos into shotwell, and change the name in shotwell, the names in the folder do not change as well. And I have clicked the "Write tags, titles and other metadata to photo files".
Is there another way?
Ton

Many have suggested this: https://github.com/tfree87/pyRenamer Some older info but still valid: https://blog.jdpfu.com/2011/01/05/tips-for-digital-photo-organiz-storage-and-archival   If you want to read photo internal data to use in name, exiftool is one of the best. man exiftool has examples. There is in synaptic for command line rename, perl based,  rename-flac  & renameutils  includes 5 tools.
